# Segfault 11 on a decimal to binary function

Tags: c

I have a function that converts decimal to binary and returns a char * of a binary:

```
void decimal2binary(int decimalNum, int size, char * charPtr){
    int decimalTemp = decimalNum;
    int modNum;

    for(int sizeTemp = size; sizeTemp >= 0; --sizeTemp){
        modNum = decimalTemp >> sizeTemp;

        if(modNum & 1){
            strcat(charPtr, "1");
        }else{
            strcat(charPtr, "0");
        }
    } 
}
```

When I try to test it in main, I get the correct out put as and then "Segmentation fault 11" with gcc compiler:

In int main() :

```
char testArr[] = "test";
char * foo = testArr;
decimal2binary(10,7, foo);
printf("%s\n", foo);
printf("asdasds\n");
```

Result :

```
test00001010
asdasds
Segmentation Fault: 11
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Shoving 13 chars into an array declared to be 5-wide probably isn't what you had in mind.

Comment: This is a common misconception in school tasks. The input number in `int decimalNum` is not decimal in any way. Instead it is in internal representation and arithmetic instructions can be used on it. The internal representation happens to be `binary`, not `decimal` in current computers. Teachers who give this type of tasks and ask students to provide a function that takes an integer should educate themselves.

Comment: @PavelŠimerda Isn't that the point of abstraction? Stop hating on abstraction, some of us happen to like it.

Comment: That's not abstraction, that's misconception. Abstraction is that those are just numbers, not decimal, not binary, i.e. we're hiding the representation because it's not important for arithmetics. To call an abstract representation of a number without any decimal features a decimal number is a fatal misunderstanding.

Comment: To add a story to it, when I was asked at school to translate decimal to binary, I created a program that translated an actual decimal representation to a binary representation and explained that this is the only way to handle such an assignment correctly. I actually used an integer type as an intermediate form, not only because I do love abstraction.

Comment: Isn't that a bit dramatic? Well that's your own interpretation. But when the user is entering the number, the user isn't thinking "let me enter 4 which has an underlying binary representation of 0100". The user is entering a *number* 4. `int decimalNumber` is an abstraction of the underlying representation. But if it makes you feel better, perhaps `int number` would have sufficed.

Comment: When the user is entering "4", he's entering the number in decimal. When the program reads it into an integer via `scanf`, it's calling a *library function* to convert the decimal into the internal representation. The function in the question turns the internal representation into binary. The program in the question tests such a function for a specific input in the internal representation. That the programmer writes it in decimal is a detail of the programming language and the specific test program. Simple facts, no need to pull in one's feelings and call it *dramatic*.

Comment: @PavelŠimerda I was actually referring to this: "To call an abstract representation of a number without any decimal features a decimal number is a fatal misunderstanding." as dramatic. But I'm pretty sure most lecturers understand such fundamentals.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61368/discussion-between-pavel-simerda-and-lews-therin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array you pass in has a size of 5 - "test\0". 
It doesn't "work" as you are writing in an invalid memory location. 
More like undefined behavior.

EDIT:

If you can't tell the size of the buffer to pass in, a suggestion might be to use realloc and grow your array. Return the pointer, but remember to free the allocated memory.

Comment: yep, you're right. I made a temporary char array of size 50 (for test purposes) and used that as an intermediate step and the seg fault went away. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting segmentation fault for attempting to write on memory addresses that are not
inside your memory segment.
Use an array of bigger size or even better use pointers and keep on realloc'ing new space
as needed.